# excel rows function: increase numbers sequentially in the same cell

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, rows, worksheet

I am using the ROWS function in an excel spreadsheet to auto increase numbers within text.
the formula i am using at the moment is this:

```
="text"&ROWS(A$1:A1)&"text"&ROWS(A$1:A1)&"text"&ROWS(A$1:A1)&"text"&ROWS(A$1:A1)&"text"&ROWS(A$1:A1)&"text"
```

which produces the following output:

(CELL A:1) text1text1text1text1text1text

The numbers increase by 1 as i copy the cells down ie:

(CELL A:2) text2text2text2text2text2text

The output i actually need is to increase the numbers sequentially by 1:

(CELL A:1) text1text2text3text4text5text

(CELL A:2) text6text7text8text9text10text  ...etc

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version

`="text"&(ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)*5+1&"text"&(ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)*5+2&"text"&(ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)*5+3&"text"&(ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)*5+4&"text"&(ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)*5+5&"text"`

*5 is based on 5 text values per cell

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i needed.  I really appreciate your help here.